# Javascript String Manipulation getting part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I have a url like the following.

http:// myipaddress/folder1/folder2/themes/index.html

Does anyone know of the best approach to always grab whats before and not including /themes/ using javscript string manipulation reg exp techniques. The first bit will regularly be different to the /themes/index.html which is static

Comment: `str.split("/themes")[0]`

Comment: if you sure that "themes/index.html" is static, just replace it with empty string `"http:// myipaddress/folder1/folder2/themes/index.html".replace("/themes/index.html", "")`

Comment: @Tommi: that approach presupposes that what *follows* `/themes` is always known in advance, which may not be the case.

Comment: OP said "the /themes/index.html which is static"

Comment: @tymeJV Why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  lookahead to get all the texts before `/themes`,

```
> var str = 'http:// myipaddress/folder1/folder2/themes/index.html';
undefined
> var patt1 = /^.*(?=\/themes)/gi;
undefined
> var result = str.match(patt1);
undefined
> console.log(result);
[ 'http:// myipaddress/folder1/folder2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript split method and remove themes from strings array given by split method and then use join method to concatenate it with your delimeter ('/')

```
function removeFromStr(str,whatToRemove){
var splitted = str.split('/'),
    filtered = splitted.filter(function(el){
        return el !== whatToRemove;
    });
    return filtered.join('/');
}
test = removeFromStr('http://myipaddress/folder1/folder2/themes/index.html','themes');

console.log(test);
```